# What is causing git am to fail when format-patch included an unchanged line as a changed line?

Tags: git, format-patch

After using git format-patch the following snippet appeared in my patch files.

```
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-﻿using Chicken.Nuggets;
+using Chicken.Nuggets;
```

Both the added and removed lines ended with a crlf line ending. This was also the first line of the file both times I encountered this issue.

When I attempted to use the patch file with `git am --ignore-whitespace *.patch` the patches with segments similar to the above would fail. I was able to easily get around the issue by removing the sections containing the unchanged changed lines, but was hoping that somebody could at least explain what could have happened, as I don't think that should have shown as a changed line in the first place and I also don't understand why applying the patch would fail since I wouldn't expect it to matter what the old and new lines were.

Comment: You're right that if the lines aren't different, they should not be shown as changed. Applying might fail if the *current* line does not match either of the removed-and-re-added lines, though.

Comment: The lines did match as far as I could see, even down to the crlf line endings. This project is just duplicated in both repositories, with a different .Net version. A diff between them only shows 3 lines different - the .Net version and the versions in Assembly.cs.

Comment: I finally figured it out as it appears to be happening quite frequently. The byte order mark is being removed when I or others save changes to a file. I couldn't see this in the patch files, but doing a binary comparison between the old file and new showed the difference.

Comment: Aha! Note that a UTF-8 byte-order-mark is useless in one sense: UTF-8 files only have one byte order, there's no question of big-vs-little-endian in the first place, so there's no need to declare them as whatever-endian. Some software insists that the mark is good because it says that the file is encoded in UTF-8, but that should be the default anyway, so some software insists on removing the mark.